# "Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning" when i try to use "$inc" operator to increment age parameter in my MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I'm trying to update my age parameter defined in this script into my mongoDB database locally but getting an error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot apply $inc to a value of non-numeric type. {_id: Objec
tId('5c3c5f5142e37c39289b7967')} has the field 'age' of non-numeric type string"

```
const {MongoClient, ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Todoapp', (err, db) =>{
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
  }
  console.log('Console to MongoDB server');

  db.collection('Users').findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: new ObjectID('5c3c5f5142e37c39289b7967')
    }, {
      $set: {
        name: 'Anshul',
    },
    $inc: {
      age: 1
    }

    },{
      returnOriginal: false
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });





  //db.close();
});
```

Comment: The error message explains the problem pretty good. Your `age` field is a string when it should be an int.

Comment: I tried to initialize it as an integer, what I'm supposed to do?How do it put it as a non string ? Thanks